# How to fallback from one regex location to another in Nginx

Tags: nginx

There is a request for the following image file without extension.

```
https://example.com/images/2022-08/abc
```

I want the above request to fall back from **Location-A** to **Location-B** when the result in Location-A is **404** error.

I have actually confirmed that the error code for missing files is 404 in Location-A.

The following code cannot fall back to location-B.
How can I correct this?

```
# location-A
# Ignore the date.
location ~ ^\/images\/([0-9\-]+)\/([0-9a-zA-Z\-_]+) {
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=2592000";
    error_page 404 = @fallback;
    proxy_pass https://subdomain.example.com/images/$2;
}

# location-B
location @fallback {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

Comment: You need [`proxy_intercept_errors on;`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors) to allow Nginx to process the error code returned through `proxy_pass`.

Comment: Correct point. Thank you very much.